# Set php mail() function to use smtp authentication

Tags: linux, email, php, smtp

So, how can I set php's `mail()` function to use smtp authentication?

I have a `web` server and then an `mail` server. All company's email, incoming or outgoing, passes through the mail server and I was wondering how to set the `web` server to use `mail()` function with SMTP authentication at the `mail` server.

Note: I need to do this globally, not to go file by file that runs the mail function in each site and start editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's built-in `mail()` function does not expose functionality to make SMTP auth possible.

You would need to re-write existing code to use something like the [PEAR Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) package.

Otherwise you may find it easier to set up a router on your web server's SMTP daemon to forward all outgoing mail to the mail server. In Exim, for example, this is accomplished with a `smart_route` definition.

Comment: these are my two only options?

Comment: I'm sure there are other alternatives including writing your own mail function wrapper, but the built-in `mail()` function, on its own, has no way of doing what you are describing.